# Перемотка, пауза и громкость фоновой музыки сайта с использованием клавиатуры

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

При загрузке моей страницы сразу включается фоновый аудиофайл. Есть ли возможность управления данным аудиофайлом при помощи клавиатуры (например, запрограммировать стрелки вправо-влево, как перемотка назад и вперед, стрелки вверх-вниз, как регулировка громкости и пробел, как пауза и воспроизведение)?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ожидаешь нажатия заданной клавиши (через keyDown, keyPress, например), проверяешь, какая клавиша нажата (через код или значение), а потом манипуляцию с плеером.